# Asynchronous progress bar on a loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, loops, asynchronous

Using MVC3, C#, jQuery, Ajax ++

My html

```
<div>
   <a href="#" id="startProcess">Start Long Running Process</a>
</div>
<br />
<div id="statusBorder">
    <div id="statusFill">
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript part part of the html

```
    var uniqueId = '<%= Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>';

    $(document).ready(function (event) {
        $('#startProcess').click(function () {
            $.post("SendToDB/StartLongRunningProcess", { id: uniqueId,
                                 //other parameters to be inserted like textbox

                                                             }, function () {
                $('#statusBorder').show();
                getStatus();
            });
            event.preventDefault;
        });
    });

     function getStatus() {
        var url = 'SendToDB/GetCurrentProgress';
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            if (data != "100") {
                $('#status').html(data);
                $('#statusFill').width(data);
                window.setTimeout("getStatus()", 100);
            }
            else {
                $('#status').html("Done");
                $('#statusBorder').hide();
                alert("The Long process has finished");
            };
        });
    }
```

This is the controller.

```
    //Some global variables. I know it is not "good practice" but it works.
    private static int _GlobalSentProgress = 0;
    private static int _GlobalUsersSelected = 0;

    public void StartLongRunningProcess(string id,
                                        //other parameters
                                        )
    {   
        int percentDone = 0;
        int sent = 0;            

        IEnumerable<BatchListModel> users;

        users = new UserService(_userRepository.Session).GetUsers(
                //several parameters)

        foreach (var c in users)
        {
                var usr = _userRepository.LoadByID(c.ID);

                var message = new DbLog
                {
                    //insert parameters
                };

                _DbLogRepository.Save(message);
                sent++;

                double _GlobalSentProgress = (double)sent / (double)_GlobalUsersSelected * 100;

                if (percentDone < 100)
                {
                    percentDone = Convert.ToInt32(_GlobalSentProgress);
        }

//this is supposed to give the current progress to the "GetStatus" in the javascript
public int GetCurrentProgress()
    {
        return _GlobalSentProgress;
    }
```

Right now the div with the progress bar never shows up. It is honestly kind of broken. But I hope you understand my logic.

In the loop doing the insertions, I do have this calculation:

```
double _GlobalSentProgress = (double)sent / (double)_GlobalUsersSelected * 100;
```

Then I convert the _GlobalSentProgress to a normal int in the

```
percentDone = Convert.ToInt32(_GlobalSentProgress);
```

so it no longer has any decimals any longer.

If only I could send this "percentDone" or "_GlobalSentProgress" variable (wich is showing perfectly how many percent I have come in the insertion) asynchronous into the "data" variable in javascript every single time it loops, it would work. Then "data" would do it's "statusFill" all the time and show the bar correctly. This is the logic I use.

I believe the word thrown around in order to accomplish this is "asynchronous". I have looked at 2 very promising guides but I was not able to make it work with my loop.

Anyone have a suggestion on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2: Outer div is named statusBorder not status.